# Вывести тип из массива объектов

Tags: typescript

Это моя схема валидации

```
[
    {
        "product_code": "HI",
        "min_amount": 3,
        "max_amount": 100,
        "total_amount": true
    },
    {
        "product_code": "SO",
        "min_amount": 4,
        "max_amount": 50,
        "total_amount": false
    }
]
```

Тип для схемы

```
interface IValidateSchema{
    product_code: string,
    min_amount: number,
    max_amount: number,
    total_amount: boolean,
}
```

У меня есть переменная `const errors = {}`, которая в последствие будет заполнятся ключами из product_code. Вопрос как вывести тип из схемы валидации, чтобы на выходе я получил тип

```
type ErrorType = {
    [key: "HI" | "SO"]: boolean
}
```

Comment: как задается схема валидации? Это тип? Объект?

Comment: Объект и тип к нему

Comment: покажи как тип описывается

Comment: Добавил интерфейс

Comment: похоже в случае с таким интерфейсом - только вручную все

Comment: как объявлена переменная схемы?

Comment: Я тяну json из файлика и паршу его в массивчик

Comment: Подозреваю, что для этого надо как минимум в `product_code: string,` иметь не `string`, а `"HI" | "SO"`.

Comment: @Istinnavvine, если тянешь из json и парсишь - то тип никак не вывести.

Comment: @Qwertiy, если бы значение было постоянным, можно было бы воспользоваться [`as const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) - и `(typeof scheme)[number]['product_code']` вернул бы нужный union

Comment: понятно, спасибо

Comment: @Grundy, я думал, схема - это именно [схема](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html).

Comment: @Qwertiy, есть вероятность, но мне кажется все проще :)

Comment: я уже вывел тип с помощью key in